# Sorting portrait and landscape images

Tags: php, arrays, math

Is it possible to sort an array of images with PHP.

As example I have array with mixed landscape and portrait images. 140 width for portrait and 280 for landscapes.

I want to create a function which check if position 1 is portrait and position 2 landscape, then position 3 must be portrait to prevent gaps in the gallery.

Answer (score 7):

use getimagesize to check portrait or landscape

PHP Code:

```
$size = getimagesize($filename); 
$width = $size[0]; 
$height = $size[1]; 
$aspect = $height / $width; 
if ($aspect >= 1) $mode = "vertical"; 
else $mode = "horizontal";
```

If you want to get the dimensions of a GD image resource rather than an image file, use this instead of getimagesize():

PHP Code:

```
$width = imagesx($img); 
$height = imagesy($img);
```

finaly, implement it to your code and just do a wished sort

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you couldn't.  Query the image size of each picture in your array using something like getimagesize().

Once you have the width of each image, sorting should be simple.